# Ansible: How to get structured YAML from OpenShift 'oc' command response?

Tags: jenkins, ansible, yaml, openshift

Ansible is launched on Jenkins and I want to connect to OpenShift and get the current entities (for example, routes).

Goal: get a single file with all entities separated by `---`.

I tried to use `to_yaml`, `from_yaml` and so on with the `oc --server` shell command, but so far nothing has worked.

What's the easiest way to get the nested part? What is the best way to take `items` from the `stdout`?
Or is it better to go some other way altogether? For example, without using `shell` module?

At the moment I've tried this:

```yaml
  - name: Get K8s items
    register: getItems
    shell: oc --server {{ os_project.host }} --namespace {{ os_project.project }} --token {{ os_token }} get -o yaml route.route.openshift.io

  - name: Write united config to file
    copy:
      content: "{{ getItems.stdout }}"
      dest: processed_templates/os_backup/os_dump_{{ version }}.yml
```

I get the following output:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
  kind: Route
  metadata:
    annotations:
      haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance: roundrobin
    <...>
      kind: Service
      name: ingressgateway-ift-shared-https-svc
      weight: 100
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

How can I get an output like:

```yaml
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance: roundrobin
  <...>
    kind: Service
    name: ingressgateway-ift-shared-https-svc
    weight: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

> *What is the best way to take `items` from the `stdout`?*

Based on the information provided, a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    getItems:
      stdout:
        apiVersion: v1
        items:
        - apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
          kind: Route
          metadata:
            annotations:
              haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance: roundrobin
              kind: Service
              name: ingressgateway-ift-shared-https-svc
              weight: 100
        kind: List
        metadata:
          resourceVersion: ""
          selfLink: ""

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ getItems.stdout['items'] | first }}"
```

result into the requested output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
    kind: Route
    metadata:
      annotations:
        haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance: roundrobin
        kind: Service
        name: ingressgateway-ift-shared-https-svc
        weight: 100
```

- Since the output is a dictionary one can get the values of the key via `getItems.stdout['items']`.
- It is returned a list with one element only. Since the final result should be a dictionary again, one can just filter for the `first` element.